# Classic ASP: How to sort a dictionary If It has class Items for values

Tags: sorting, dictionary, multidimensional-array, asp-classic

I need to sort a dictionary by its key, but the values are class items.

Here is the class:

```
CLASS Person
  PUBLIC PersonID                   
  PUBLIC PersonName                         
  PUBLIC GenderID
  PUBLIC PersonAdditional                   
  PRIVATE SUB class_initialize()
      PersonID = null
      PersonName = null
      GenderID = null
      PersonAdditional = null
  END SUB
END CLASS
```

And here is my dictionary, filled with data from an array:

```
Set dict = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

FOR i = 0 TO UBOUND(arr_People)

    key_person = arr_People(i).GenderID & arr_People(i).PersonName

    dict.Add key_person, new Person
        dict.Item(key_person).PersonName = arr_People(i).PersonName
        dict.Item(key_person).GenderID = arr_People(i).GenderID
        dict.Item(key_person).PersonID = arr_People(i).PersonID
        dict.Item(key_person).PersonAdditional = arr_People(i).PersonAdditional

NEXT
```

I use this function for sorting, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Function SortDictionary(objDict,intSort)

Dim strDict()
Dim objKey
Dim strKey,strItem
Dim X,Y,Z
Z = objDict.Count
If Z > 1 Then
  ReDim strDict(Z,2)
  X = 0
  For Each objKey In objDict
      strDict(X,dictKey)  = CStr(objKey)
      strDict(X,dictItem) = CStr(objDict(objKey))
      X = X + 1
  Next
  For X = 0 to (Z - 2)
    For Y = X to (Z - 1)
      If StrComp(strDict(X,intSort),strDict(Y,intSort),vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
          strKey  = strDict(X,dictKey)
          strItem = strDict(X,dictItem)
          strDict(X,dictKey)  = strDict(Y,dictKey)
          strDict(X,dictItem) = strDict(Y,dictItem)
          strDict(Y,dictKey)  = strKey
          strDict(Y,dictItem) = strItem
      End If
    Next
  Next
  objDict.RemoveAll
  For X = 0 to (Z - 1)
    objDict.Add strDict(X,dictKey), strDict(X,dictItem)
  Next
End If
End Function
```

It gives me the following error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

on this row:

```
strDict(X,dictItem) = CStr(objDict(objKey)
```

I'm assuming that this happens because the values in the dictionary contains class instead of just a string or integer, but I don't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a workaround that you can use:

- Create another array containing only the keys of the dictonary
- Sort the array
- Read the dictionary values by iterating trough the array of keys

And here's the code:

```
Set dict = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set arr_personKeys = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

FOR i = 0 TO UBOUND(arr_People)

    key_person = arr_People(i).GenderID & arr_People(i).PersonName
    arr_personKeys.Add key_person 

    dict.Add key_person, new Person
        dict.Item(key_person).PersonName = arr_People(i).PersonName
        dict.Item(key_person).GenderID = arr_People(i).GenderID
        dict.Item(key_person).PersonID = arr_People(i).PersonID
        dict.Item(key_person).PersonAdditional = arr_People(i).PersonAdditional
NEXT

arrLength_personKeys  = arr_personKeys.count - 2

SortArray arr_personKeys,arrLength_personKeys
```

And here is the sorting function:

```
Function SortArray(arrayForSorting, arraySize)
    for a = arraySize To 0 Step -1
        for j = 0 to a
            if arrayForSorting(j)>arrayForSorting(j+1) then
                temp=arrayForSorting(j+1)
                arrayForSorting(j+1)=arrayForSorting(j)
                arrayForSorting(j)=temp
            end if
        next
    next 
End Function
```

Now you can iterate trough your sorted dictionary like this:

```
For i = 0 To arrLength_personKeys + 1           
    key = arr_personKeys(i)

    Response.write dict(key).PersonID
    Response.write dict(key).PersonName 
    Response.write dict(key).GenderID
    Response.write dict(key).PersonAdditional
Next
```